# place coordinate at pgfplots tick (like for ticklabel)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I built the following based off of the example in the Pgfplots manual, p324 (`typeset ticklabels with strut`)

It showcases the possibility to name the ticklabel nodes for later use.

Is any thing similar possible with the ticks themselves (although they must presumably not be defined as nodes, but as paths ?)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
      xmax = 4,
      xtick={1,2.5,3},
      xticklabel style={draw, name=tickLabel \ticknum},
      xtick style = {red, very thick}, % --------------- how to mimic the above ?
      domain=0:4,
    ]
    \addplot[]{x};
  \end{axis}
  \draw[blue,very thick, <->] (tickLabel 0) -- (tickLabel 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So basically, how to grab the very thick red ticks, be it those on top or at bottom ?

Cheers,

Comment: By default there will (most probably) be no such coordinates/nodes. But if you would let us know what you want to do with them, maybe we could provide another solution that satisfies your needs. Please edit your question accordingly by adding more text or also a sketch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real intention for getting access to the tick marks is unclear to me. Maybe, the following helps:

Package `pgfplots` supports several coordinate systems:

- `axis cs`: This coordinate system is used for the contents of the plot, the x coordinates of the red ticks are given by 1, 2.5, and 3.
- `axis description cs` can be used to get the y coordinates of the horizontal axes: 0, 1
- The previous coordinate systems can be combined to get the points on the axes, where the red ticks start, e.g.:

  ```
  ({axis cs:2.5, 0} |- {axis description cs:0, 1})
  ```

  The `|-` operator takes the horizontal component of the coordinate on the left and the vertical component of the coordinate on the right.
- The length of the major ticks can be saved in a macro `\MajorTickLength`:

  ```
  \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/major tick length}{\MajorTickLength}
  ```

The following example draws an arrow from the top of the bottom tick mark for 3 to the bottom of the top tick mark of 1:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
      xmax = 4,
      xtick={1,2.5,3},
      xticklabel style={draw, name=tickLabel \ticknum},
      xtick style = {red, very thick},
      domain=0:4,
    ]
    \addplot[]{x};
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/major tick length}{\MajorTickLength}
    \path
      ({axis cs:3, 0} |- {axis description cs:0, 0})
      ++(0, \MajorTickLength) coordinate (tick bot 3)
      ({axis cs:1, 0} |- {axis description cs:0, 1})
      ++(0, -\MajorTickLength)
      coordinate (tick top 1)
    ;
  \end{axis}
  \draw[blue, very thick, <->] (tickLabel 0) -- (tickLabel 1);
  \draw[blue, very thick, <->] (tick bot 3) -- (tick top 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My motivation was to be able to automate somewhat drawing `|-` between ticks as in [this other question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335801/draw-projection-to-the-axes-of-list-of-points-on-a-curve)