# Draw projection to the axes of list of points on a curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to have a simple way of drawing the following red lines, given a certain function (here `f(x) = x^2`).

[image: what I want to draw (the red polylines)]

Here is one of the ideas I have had so far (that mostly feel silly) :

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
  1
  2.5
  3
} \myTable % -- I can't use this method with the `expr` syntax ? 

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
      xtick = {1,2.5,3}, 
      ytick = {1,6.25,9}, 
      domain = 0:4,
      axis lines = middle,
    ]
    \addplot [thick, blue] {x^2} node [near end, anchor = east] {$y = x^2$};
    \addplot [xcomb, red] table[x index = 0,y expr=x^2] {
        1
      2.5
      3
    };
    \addplot [ycomb, red] table[x index = 0,y expr=x^2] {
        1
      2.5
      3
    };
    %\addplot table[x index=0,y expr=x^2] {\myTable}; % does not work ?!
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Another way of doing things I came up with is something like

```
draw [myStyle] (axis cs: 1, 0) |- (axis cs: 0, 1) ; 
draw [myStyle] (axis cs: 2.5, 0) |- (axis cs: 0, 6.25) ;
```

repeated for each point I want to place,

but I suspect there might be some much more clever way to do this.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6):

Ok I found a better idea with a `for` loop :

*(I changed the function to showcase that it works with named functions, like `sqrt(x)`, and not only `x^2`)*

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
      xtick = {1,6.25,9},
      ytick = {1,2.5,3},
      domain = 0:10, samples=100,
      axis lines = middle,
    ]
    \addplot [thick, blue] {sqrt(x)} node [pos=.4, anchor = south east, inner sep=1pt] {$y = \sqrt{x}$};

    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach {1,6.25,9}
      {
        \draw [red] (axis cs: #1, 0) |- (axis cs: 0, {sqrt(#1)}) ;
      }
%    % variant : 
%    \pgfplotsextra
%    {
%      \foreach \x in {1,6.25,9}
%      {
%        \draw [red] (axis cs: \x, 0) |- (axis cs: 0, {sqrt(\x)}) ;
%      }
%    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Cheers,

### Edit :

- added support for named points (instead of numbered points) and automatically generating tick list.
- One could also automatically generate a TickLabelList...

here we go :

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\gdef \xTicks {0}  
\gdef \yTicks {0}  
%\gdef\symbols{{"a","b","myPointWithAnIntricateName"}} %------- variant with a list 

\tikzmath
{
  integer \i ; 
  function f(\x)
  {
    return sqrt(\x);
  };
  let \symbols{0} = a; %the hash for point names --------comment for the list variant
  let \symbols{1} = b;
  let \symbols{2} = myPointWithAnIntricateName;
  \t{a} = 1 ; % here \t stands for the abscissa
  \t{b} = 6.25 ;
  \t{myPointWithAnIntricateName} = 9 ;
  for \i in {0,...,2}% 
  {
    let \theSymbol =\symbols{\i}; % ---------------------comment for the list variant
    %\theSymbol=array(\symbols,\i); % -----------------uncomment for the list variant
    \y{\theSymbol} = f(\t{\theSymbol}) ; %showcase one way to define the hash for y coordinates
    {
      \xdef\xTicks{\xTicks, \t{\theSymbol}} % append value to ticks list
      \xdef\yTicks{\yTicks, \y{\theSymbol}}
    };
  };
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
      xtick = \xTicks,
      ytick = \yTicks,
      domain = 0:10, samples=100,
      axis lines = middle,
    ]
    \addplot [thick, blue] {f(x)} node [pos=.4, anchor = south east, inner sep=1pt] {$y = f(x)$};

    \pgfplotsextra
    {
      \foreach \theSymbol in {a,b,myPointWithAnIntricateName}%
      {
        \draw [red] (axis cs: {\t{\theSymbol}}, 0) |- (axis cs: 0, {\y{\theSymbol}}) ;
      }
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Cheers,